# Adobe Illustrator producing tiny boxes between words

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

Not sure what I pressed, but my type in Illustrator is producing tiny boxes in between each of the words (like MS Word does with its preview on). While these boxes don't print, they are very annoying. How do I turn this function off?

Comment: Does it do that with every font? Can you upload a screenshot of these boxes?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about hidden characters. Turning on hidden characters shows all nonprinting characters such as spaces, returns, tabs etc.

Turn it on and off by going to *Type → Show Hidden Characters* or hitting <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

[image: Illustrator Hidden Characters]